# Increment count before update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `count` column in my `tags` table. I wanna increment tag count if a tag is just added to the post while updating, and it's already inside db. I added this to my post model:

```rails
before_update :increment_tag

def increment_tag
  db_post = Post.find_by_id(self)
  self.tags.each do |tag|
    unless db_post.tags.include? tag
      tag.update_attribute("count", tag.count + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

I get the post from db and test if the current tag is already in db, if it is, nothing happens, if it's not there, it should update count field. But for some reason this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have a Count column in a tag. You should in stead set up your models propperly so you could do the following:

```
db_post.tags.count
```

If you do it right, you can get this in your tag:

```
tag.post.tags.count
```

If your aim is to find how many times the tag is used in a post, in total, you can simply count the instances in the TagToPostColumn (if you got one), which you need to sine this is a many-to-many relation.

Then you do:

> TagToPostColumn.where(tag_id: someTag.id).count

`count` is a standard attribute, and you should never have to keep track of this yourself, unless you actually need a column called count that tracks something other than the models you have in the database. But then it is a good idea to name it something else than count, since it can lead to ambiguous attributes.

Also, i find it very strange that you are doing this:

> db_post = Post.find_by_id(self)

Why are you not just using the self parameter, in stead of doing a db lookup to find the post you already have.

Comment: What if you want to sort tags by importance using SQL rather than pure Ruby (which may be slower) ?

Comment: This is a completely different question, but assuming you have a importance column in tags you do Tag.all.order('importance ASC'). If you do not have an importance column, you need to figure out how to do this yourself. What "importance" is, is up you.

Comment: I mean he may want his count column to sort tags by the amount of posts referencing them.

Comment: I wanna give different font size to each Tag based on the amount of posts have used them. This solution won't work that way. I used "self" to compare the instantiated post (but not yet saved to db) with the one in the database.

Comment: Then what I said above will help you: <p style="font-size<%=TagToPostColumn.where(tag_id: someTag.id).count.to_s%>">whateverText</p>